# Layout of a card in Google Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I have a set of cards in a cardScrollView. I want to set the layout of these cards. I have posted the code i have done till now which is rather incomplete. I am stuck on the point where i can set the view of a card. I have seen setViews() method for livecards but for Card class there is just a toView() method. Any input on how i can set the xml layout to the cards ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < subscribesource.size(); i++) {

        Card card = new Card(this);

        identifysource = subscribesource.get(i);
        System.out.println("cardtext" + identifysource);
        card.setText(identifysource);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.activity_main, null );
        View cardview = card.toView();


        sourceCard.add(card);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you heard about [CardBuilder](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/CardBuilder)? This is new feature in XE21. It includes EMBED_INSIDE class which help you to include your desired custom layouts.

Answer (score -2):

don't bother with Cards if you want custom layout(s).

Comment: I completely agree. Not only will your design be more flexible (and be portable to android phones/tablets, fwiw), but updates to gdk won't break your app needlessly.

Comment: your input does not help at all. What is the alternative way to create a card like UI without cards?

Comment: ...to create a layout. You can make a layout look however you want, Cards UI being a very limited subset of all the possibilities.

Comment: It's funny that people are downvoting this question...is Glass not dead? I offered very good advice: by working with Cards you greatly limit what you can do, while custom layouts are relatively unlimited.